# how to view git stashes without the need to reset?

Tags: git, version-control, git-stash

git newbie here: I have a list of stashes:

```
aws-0292@procolharum MINGW64 ~/phuber/magic (master)
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: On master: 30 or 31
stash@{1}: On master: music
stash@{2}: On master: this party
```

I would like to see each stash, so I do:

```
$ git stash apply stash@{0}
```

works great! I can see what stash#0; now I wish to move to stash#1, in order to do so I have to clear everything so I do:

```
$ git reset --hard
```

and then

```
$ git stash apply stash@{1}
```

I'm quite sure my process is somewhat wrong, is there a better way without the need of git reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `git checkout` a stash:

```
git checkout stash@{0}
```

And when you're done inspecting it, switch back to your branch:

```
git checkout main
```

(Or whichever branch name is appropriate.)

---

Since a stash entry is just a commit reference, you can also use [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) to check out the stash in a different directory:

```
git worktree add ../checked-out-stash stash@{0}
```

When you're done:

```
git worktree remove ../checked-out-stash
```

Comment: perfect! so whats the diff between apply and checkout (in other words when should I use apply?)

Comment: For the sake of accuracy, note that here we're comparing `git checkout` and `git stash apply`; `git apply` is a very different command. You use `git stash apply` when you want to incorporate the changes in your stash into your current branch. You use `git checkout` if you simply want to inspect the stash but not apply the changes.

Comment: You must be a lawyer :-) yes: git stash apply. Got it. Thanks again!!!